# Symfony 3 callback validation not being called

Tags: forms, symfony-3.3

I have a form in Symfony 3 where I want the user to upload a file or fill in a comment (or both).

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(
        $approvalRequest,
        array(
            'validation_groups' => array('revocation_proposal')
        )
    )
        ->add(
                'deletionComment',
                TextareaType::class,
                array(
                    'attr' => array(
                        'cols' => 70,
                        'rows' => 10
                    ),
                    'required' => false //otherwise html will force it to be required
                )
            )
        ->add('deletionTemplate',
               ResearchTemplateType::class,
                array('label' => 'Deletion Form',
                    'required' => false)) //otherwise html will force it to be required

        ->add(
            'cancel',
            SubmitType::class,
            array(
                'label' => 'Cancel'
            )
        )
        ->add('revoke', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Revoke Approval',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'btn-danger')
        ))

        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

I am trying to enforce that at least one of the two (the comment or the file) must be present in order for the form to be valid using [callbacks](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html).

In my entity I have:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if (is_null($this->getDeletionComment()) && is_null($this->getDeletionTemplate())) {
        $context->buildViolation('You must write a deletion comment or upload a deletion template')
            ->atPath('deletionTemplate')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

But it is not being called. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: have you try to dump something in the callback function to make shure is not reaching that point? Also check you are validating the entity or the form(check the form belongs to that entity).

Comment: I have a breakpoint on the callback that never gets triggered on debug, so I am fairly sure it is not being called. The entity does not have any @assert (apart from the validate function)

Comment: Do you finally found a solution ?
I am stuck with the exactly same behaviour _(on a collection object)_
I tried to place callback method on both `Parent` class and `ChildrenCollection` class with a `dump("Parent")` or `dump("Child")`.
I tried to place `@Assert\Callback` annotation on top of class and on top of method.. Still not working ! It's driving me crazy !